# Carousel inside Panel - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel, carousel

how to put carousel inside the panel ? bootstrap
im trying to put carousel inside a panel, but the images doesnt show

```
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
       <div class="panel-body"><font size="2" face="arial">
      <div class="container">
      <div id="MyCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to= "0" class="item active"></li>
       <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to= "1"></li>
       <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to= "2"></li>

  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
       </div>
         <img scr="\darryl\images\front.jpg" alt="Ched" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
<img scr="\darryl\images\front.jpg" alt="Ched" class="img-responsive">
```

by this:

```
<img scr="/darryl/images/front.jpg" alt="Ched" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
<img scr=
```

It should instead be

```
<img src=
```